# Can a Unique constraint on multiple Columns add indexes separately on those columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with structure shown below :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblvideolikes (
  itemid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  videoid integer NOT NULL,
  userid integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT liked_video_user UNIQUE(videoid,userid)
)
```

I have a lot of select queries with userid and videoid. I want to know whether adding unique constraint on both columns are sufficient or Do I need to do indexing on both of them as well. I have searched a lot about this but nothing makes it clear.

Comment: Yes Tim, I think if I do select with both columns then, unique constraint will work as automatically adds unique index. But what if I only perform select either with userid or videoid. Does unique constraint is helpful in this case or I need to add indexing as well.

Comment: AFAIK the index will still help even with one column.

Comment: Ok, Do I need to index both columns(videoid and userid) or only one will be fine ?

Comment: As you already mentioned, the unique constraint you already have is an index on both columns.

Comment: Ok Tim, Also, For constraint like UNIQUE(videoid,userid)

Does the order for where clause also matter like if write
"where videoid = 1 and userid = 1" or
where userid = 1 and videoid = '1'

both will work with unique constraint UNIQUE(videoid,userid) ?

Comment: Order of columns in WHERE will not matter, but order of columns in index will matter as it won't be used when you query only by userid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to enforce the unique combination of both columns, you have to create the unique index on both of them.

Postgres will use that index as well if your `where` clause only has a condition on the first column of the index (the usual "it depends" on index usage still applies here).

Postgres is able to use a column that is not the leading column of an index for a `where` condition - however that is less efficient then using a leading column.

I would put that column first that is used more often as single `where` condition. The order of the columns does not matter for the uniqueness.

If the usage of (only) the second column is as frequent as using the (only) first column, then adding an additional index with only the second column could make sense, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS videolikes (
  itemid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  videoid integer NOT NULL,
  userid integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT liked_video_user UNIQUE(videoid,userid)
);

create index on videolikes (userid);
```

The unique index would then be used for conditions on only `videoid` and (equality) conditions using both columns. The second index would be used for conditions on only the `userid`

---

Unrelated, but:

The `itemid` primary key is pretty much useless with the above setup. You needlessly increase the size of the table and add another index that needs to be maintained. You can simply leave it out and declare `videoid, userid` as the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS videolikes (
  videoid integer NOT NULL,
  userid integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_videolikes primary key (videoid,userid)
);

create index on videolikes (userid);
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer `create unique index on videolikes (userid, videoid);`, basically it will support (more) index-only scans.

Comment: @joop: if you always use both columns in the `where` clause the order of the columns does not really matter. If the majority of queries only use `userid` then of course, `userid` should be the first column.

Comment: I understand that. But for a (N:M) junction table, the additional *reversed-order* index will cover all cases.

Comment: So you mean instead of the additional index only on `(userid)`?

Comment: Yes. It will in fact make the base table more or less redundant, because any information in it could also be obtained by just consulting one of the indexes.

Answer (score -2):

Indexing on both columns separately is a better idea if you are going to do frequent queries from both sides.

Adding unique constraints is subjective - if a `userid` likes a `videoid` just once, then it makes sense, however, this would have additional performance impact due to the unique constraint.